# .net, c# post to php page

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, authentication

I have a website that is primarily PHP but we have built some new pages in c# .net.  I need to be able to post (i think) to the PHP page.

The PHP page has a login that takes the login name and password.   I am trying to allow my .net page to have a login that directs to the PHP page and once there the user is already logged in.

I believe I can post the data to the PHP page... is that correct?

If so, can someone share a code snippet that points me in the right direction?

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: `I believe I can post the data to the PHP page... is that correct?` basically yes, but the PHP login is most likely to work with sessions. So you may get a session cookie back that you need to use for any subsequent request in order to be recognized as logged in. Just as a heads up (I know nothing about C# so I can't help with code)

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a `cURL` version for c#, the easy way would be to set that up if you can. Some information on using cURL with .NET can be found [here](http://www.carballude.es/namespace/2009/03/14/curl-library-for-c-dotnet/) and there are a few other resources on Google for `c# curl`

Answer (score 0):

There are lots and lots of ways. I prefer javascript ( with jquery) ajax calls

```
$.post('login.php', function(data) {
  alert( "returned " + data + " from php page");
});
```

see [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) for more details.

If you need to do this serverside (in the c# code behind), let me know, I will write up some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference between submitting a form post to a PHP script or to a C# application or to whatever program written in whatever language. How the data is transferred is defined by Internet standards.

Of course, different implementations may have slightly different behaviors. For instance, PHP considers all input names that have square brackets in their name to be part of an array.

Comment: If that's the case, can't I do something like the following:

WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create("http://some.php.page");
wr.Method = "POST";
wr.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

string sDataToPost = "Name=UserName&Password=SomePassword";

Stream rs = wr.GetRequestStream();
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(rs);
sw.Write(sDataToPost);